# future spec custom elements

Tags: html, components

I want to make a desktop app with electronjs. For this I want to use custom elements. (not Polymer)

But [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements/Custom_Elements_with_Classes) is a note that the spec will be rewritten:

> Spec for Custom Elements will be rewritten in early 2016. All current
>   implementation are experimental and the upcoming standard will not be
>   compatible with these. Web sites using Custom Elements are likely to
>   be broken in the near future.

Are there any updates in this? What will change? Are there new specs available? Where can I find more information on this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Custom Elements W3C Editor's Draft](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) specification is available on GitHub. It was last updated on June 1, 2016 (as of this writing) though you can expect it to continue to be updated. To answer your first question, yes, there are updates and you can see them directly at the spec. Which also answers your third and fourth questions.

Because it is a draft, you cannot expect any browser to support it yet (though some claim to). Polyfills are your best bet if you want to use it now, knowing that since you are using bleeding edge technology you will need to stay on top of browser implementations and constantly review what works.

Because [it lives on GitHub](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/), you can file bugs against the spec if you want a say in how it progresses (it is not tech support, however). Looking at open issues essentially answers your second question.

As for browser support, [Can I Use is tracking](http://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements) where it stands today including who does and doesn't have it on their roadmap. Note that browsers who claim to support it are supporting an incomplete spec that will change. That same page also has a link to lots of handy resources to help get you up to speed.